# Unable to display chart using API call in chartjs in the context of Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, linechart

Im trying to display chart using chartjs by calling API, but unable to do so.

Here s my LineChart.vue:

```
<script>
import {Line, mixins} from 'vue-chartjs' // We specify what type of chart we want from vue-chartjs and the mixins module
const { reactiveProp } = mixins
export default { //We are extending the base chart class as mentioned above
  extends: Line,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  data () {
    return {
      options: { //chart options
        lineTension: 0,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [
            {
              scaleLabel: {
                display: false
              },
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
                callback (value, index, values) {
                  return `${value  }%`
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          xAxes: [
            {
              type: 'time',
              time: {
                unit: 'month'
              },
              scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: ''
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    // this.chartData is created in the mixin
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
  }
}
</script>
```

And here is my Home.vue where i have imported the LineChart:

```
<template>
  <div class="chart">
    <line-chart :chart-data="datacollection"></line-chart>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import LineChart from './LineChart'
import axios from 'axios'
import DateTime from 'luxon'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      date: {},
      challenge: {},
      datacollection: {}
    }
  },
  component: {LineChart},
  created() {
    this.fillData()
  },
  mounted () {
    this.fillData()
  },
  methods: {
    fillData () {
      axios.get('https://my_api_goes_here')
        .then(response => {
          const results = response.data

          const dateresult = results.map(a => a.date)
          const challengeresult = results.map(a => a.challenge)

          this.date = dateresult
          this.challenge = challengeresult

          this.datacollection = {
            labels: [this.date].map(labels => DateTime.fromMillis(labels * 1000).toFormat('MMM yyyy')),
            datasets: [
              {
                data: [this.challenge],
                label: 'Africa',
                borderColor: '#7367F0'
              }
            ]
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Dont know why the chart did not appear even though my other resources have been loaded from the API call, when i checked out my console, this is what error im getting:

```
TypeError: results.map is not a function
```

Please check out my logic and let me where the error is.

Comment: Could you show the result of `console.log(results)` after `const results = response.data.data`.

Comment: It actually returns a object which contains date array and challenge array

Comment: I want to make sure that the `results` variable is not undefined since you use `results.map` which that's the error means you call `map` on some undefined variable.

Comment: Now i checked out and i tried console.log(results) after "const results = response.data" , so in console the object is returned (Actual data from API ) and "TypeError: results.map is not a function" as a error

Comment: User 28 can you help me in this.

Comment: The `map()` function only work with `Array`. Are you sure that your `results` is an array?